# How can I import .java file in eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I downloaded Java exercises from exercism.io, I use the Eclipse IDE. I can create new projects in Eclipse and work on them, but can't figure out how to import 'filename.java' and adjust that!

How can I do it? I'm using Ubuntu, do you recommend me to use a different IDE than Eclipse for Java projects?

Comment: I think eclipse is just fine. What do you mean by _import filename.java_ ? `.java` are source files. Is it a file you need to write, or is it a compiled one you want to use in another file/class ?

Comment: @AbbéRésina I got HelloWorld.java  compiled file and I want to use it in the same dir as it is. It does not work in this way?  I might misunderstood the way how it works?

Comment: http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~kaharris/10200/tutorials/eclipse/Step_04.html

Comment: in eclipse right click on the package you want the file in. select import. in the following window under general select file system and search for the file you want to import. if you just want to edit the source code you can also use a texteditor for that

Comment: You have to be aware that in Java there is a strong relationship between directories where java source files are and the notion of `package`. Do you have a `package` declaration at the beginning or your `Helloworld.java` and `Filename.java` files ?

Comment: @AbbéRésina many thanks the help. i did not know what is the difference between IDE and text editor. I made the investigation so downloaded Geany. with that is works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create a new JavaProject
- Create a new class in that java project (located in workspace)
- Name the class the same as the .java you want to import
- Then simply copy and paste your java code into Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Go to File -> Import -> Genereal -> FileSystem -> Then select a directory of the file located and then -> select the files you want to import thats it. This is for eclipse Mars

Answer (score 0):

There is this One way you need to create a new java project in Eclipse then you need to navigate to workspace of Eclipse which is where eclipse stores all java files then locate the project folder you created and then copy-paste all those java files in this project folder.